# Call public void function from different activity android

Tags: android, android-activity, static, void

How can I call public void function from **FirstActivity** in **SecondActivity**?

```
  // FirstActivity

        public void thisFunction(){
         // do something 
         // do something  
        }
```

in `Second Activity`

```
if(x){
FirstActivity.thisFunction();
}
```

but returns error:

```
Non-static method 'thisFunction()' cannot be reference from a static context
```

Comment: this is a classic problem consider, event bus or rxandroid

Comment: If your function on FirstActivity is `static`, you can define it inside a `public class Utils` for example, in a separate class. Then, on SecondActivity you can call `Utils.yourStaticFunction()`. Don't know if this helps.

Comment: I think the error defines itself, I'll agree with @statosdotcom but instead of defining static function, you can call using passing context.

Answer (score 0):

Static functions are functions of class and don't depend on any objects of that class

Class.staticFunction() (no need to instantiate), you can call it everywhere

```
public static void thisFunction(){
     // do something 
     // do something  
    }
```

Then in SecondActivity:

```
FirstActivity.thisFunctions();
```

Comment: Yes, but this is rarely a good idea and doing so outside of a utility class or singleton pattern probably indicates a design error.  You'll also quickly discovery that static methods in Android have a hard time accomplishing much unless passed a valid Context or similar.